# .Htaccess remove .php and url rewrite not working together

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a `RewriteRule` that removes `.php` from the end of each URL, it works fine when written along. I have another `RewriteRule` that rewrites my URL and enables me to type `example.com/page/25/Dominic` instead of `example.com/page.php?id=25&name=Dominic`. These two `RewriteRule`s will not work at the same time though.

I have tried them both and they do work independently.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) page.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]

#This one breaks the page and causes a 500 internal server error if the Rule above is used as well. 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC] [QSA] [L]
```

`example.com/home` should work without the `.php` extension and the URL rewrite for `page.php` should work as well.

Comment: To clarify... "I have a `RewriteRule` that removes `.php`" - This rule _adds_ the `.php` extension, it doesn't "remove" it.

Comment: Yes thats correct MrWhite. It actually adds .php to the end if you did not

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem when I edited my .htaccess. I think it has to do with the fact that your server goes looking for /page/ as a directory, which doesn’t actually exist on your server (it’s just a virtual one created through the rewrite rule, or something along those lines).

Just change the name of page.php (blogpage.php, userpage.php,...) and it should work.

**Edit :**

```
Options All -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ pages.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Jay the url rewrite actually works one page/. The problem is that .htaccess will not remove .php from any of the pages when this Rule is applied:  RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) page.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: Yes, I ran into the exact same issue, until I changed the name of the php page. Did you try my code (and changing the name of the page)?

Comment: "and changing the name of the page" - You should not need to change the name of `page.php` providing `MultiViews` is not enabled. It has been disabled in the above code, so this part should be OK.

Comment: Jay the code you provided above adds the .php extension but threw a 500 internal error for the page url rewrite part.

Comment: Actually both of these lines work but they just won't work being active at the exact same time. I have to comment one out.                                     
#RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ pages.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

Comment: I edited my post. This is the **exact code** I am using, which works (for me). If this doesn't work then I won't know what else to suggest.